# auto increment by specific column's data

Tags: mysql, database

In a table like below,

```
category | feeds | content
==========================
1          1       something
1          2       bar
1          3       foo
2          1       blah
2          2       um
1          4       things
```

How should I do to work auto_increment independently (distinguished by 'category')?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you want describe in some details.

Comment: @K.D oh I'm just wondering how I can make a query to organize like that. ('feeds' column increases separately)

Comment: why don't you normalize tables? Split into two tables (category & feeds)

Comment: @Mohank what do you mean by? actually, what I am going to do is to make a couple of boards whose data is saved in one db table. and the boards are identified by 'category' field.

Comment: How do you want to use the field after adding an incremental row_number() for each group ?

Comment: You might need a trigger before insert. Inside the trigger select max(feeds)+1 into new_feed from table_name where content = NEW.content;

Comment: @Logs Oh, there will be a couple of boards and each board will be distinguished by 'category' key. And after then, the records which would be grouped by category will be shown at the each board.

Comment: @martonohalim could you explain it more specific? I am kind of new to this area :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to oracle we have `ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION BY` statement but for Mysql it is still tricky to implement this one. As most probably we will use this implementation to limit data either descending/ascending order across groups.

Here you go with the similar implementation for your reference:

```
SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @category=category 
THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS feeds,@category:=category AS category, content
FROM table1, (SELECT @row_number:=0,@category:='') AS t
ORDER BY category;
```

[SQLFiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d29cb5/16)

Comment: oh this is what I've been looking for. Could you give me more hints? I don't get the meaning of the @ mark and the ':=' mark.

Comment: @Hoon you mean it auto increment by inserting or by selecting? If by selecting the above query seems correct and I mention a trigger is the one used before insert/ when inserting. Something like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f4f5/1

Comment: here @row_number,@category is an user defined variable (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html). I am just resetting & rotating the row_number for each category.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
alter table [tableName] add autoID int auto_increment primary key;
```

This query will add 1 new column.

The result

```
category | feeds | content   | autoID
=====================================
1          1       something   1
1          2       bar         2
1          3       foo         3
2          1       blah        4
2          2       um          5
1          4       things      6
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I'm afraid this is not what I am looking for. I was trying making 'feeds' field to be AUTO_INCREMENT. Anyways, thanks!