# Calculating sum of limited rows of mysql table?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am working on drupal [website](http://www.sarbezan.com), and I want to display limited number of terms. But I failed, on running the query, I simplified the query to ask.

I want to calculate sum of limited rows of mySQL table, but unfortunately, mySQL rise an [Unknown column](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b142f/1) 'node.node_id' in 'where clause' error.

Query work on [PostgreSQL (SQLFiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/b142f/4/0).
I have following schema

```
create table rating (
  node_id int,
  rank int
);

create table node (
  node_id int
);

insert into node
(node_id)
values
(1),
(2);

insert into rating
(node_id, rank)
values
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(1, 5),
(1, 7),
(2, 5),
(2, 7),
(2, 11),
(2, 13)
;
```

And my query is

```
select node.node_id, (
  select sum(rank)
  from (
    select child_rating.rank
    from rating as child_rating
    where child_rating.node_id = node.node_id
    limit 3
  ) as _child

) as sum
from node
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/b142f/4/0) for expected result. (Or see following picture for expected result at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/b142f/4/0).

[image]

I am wondering if some one help me. Thanks

Comment: can you provide the end result that you are expecting ?

Comment: I add expected result image.

Comment: are you sure there aint no typos ?  'parint_rating.node_id'

Comment: @Logan, Thanks for your attention, everything is OK, now. You can check sqlfiddle link.

Comment: One thing I must mention is, the query is run without any problem on postgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, it is always tricky to limit the records based on each groups.

Following sql query gives you the solution:

```
select node_id, sum(rank) from (
SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @node_id=node_id 
THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_num,@node_id:=node_id AS node_id, rank
FROM rating, (SELECT @row_number:=0,@node_id:='') AS t
  ORDER BY node_id
  )t1
where row_num <= 3
group by node_id
;
```

SQL fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b142f/5

P.S: Pl take a look at the following link in which I have answered couple of days back. 
[auto increment by specific column's data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272553/auto-increment-by-specific-columns-data/26273825#26273825)

Comment: thanks for your reply, it seems good, is there any standard sql query instead of mysql specific query!?

Comment: I guess not, if it was oracle. I would have approached differently using partition over row_number(). Syntax & some times approach changes across DBs.